# Why adding external dll dependency in Blazor WASM shared project causing exception when deployed in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I've created a Blazor WASM project in .NET6. In my use case, I need to select a file and that file will be processed by an external dll, it will process the data and return some output.

This external dll I've added in Shared project and from Client project in index.rajor, I'm calling respective methods of this dll.
This external dll is .net 6 compiled dll.

In VS2022, when I ran, it worked smoothly. But when I published and deployed in IIS, I've got issues (pasted below).

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Invalid type TestApp.Shared.TestService for instance field TestApp.Client.Pages.Index:<Svc>k__BackingField
System.TypeLoadException: Invalid type TestApp.Shared.TestService for instance field TestApp.Client.Pages.Index:<Svc>k__BackingField
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo(RuntimeType , RuntimeType )
   at System.RuntimeType.IsAssignableFrom(Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteTableFactory.<GetRouteableComponents>g__GetRouteableComponents|4_0(List`1 , Assembly )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteTableFactory.GetRouteableComponents(RouteKey )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteTableFactory.Create(RouteKey )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.RefreshRouteTable()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean isNavigationIntercepted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.RunOnNavigateAsync(String path, Boolean isNavigationIntercepted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<RunOnNavigateAsync>b__1(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder , RenderFragment , Exception& )
```

I've tried adding all the artifacts in published folder but still i'm not able to get over with this System.TypeLoadException.

Comment: You can't troubleshoot your problem based on these error messages, you need more error messages, you can try to check if there are more error messages in Event Viewer or console.